# Displaying Facebook Events on website with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using the facebook SDK for javascript. I have take the sample code and in the browser console I can see that I am retrieving the data correctly

```
index.html:377 API response 
Object {data: Array[7], paging: Object}
data: Array[7]
0: Object
description: "This is just an event"
id: "1631011590449872"
name: "Event Testing"
__proto__: Object...
```

but I am having a horrible time figuring out how to display the data via javascript / jquery on the web page. I have seen examples of php but I would rather attempt this in javascript / jquery.

Here is the script where I go and get the data

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({ cache: true });
  $.getScript('//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js',function(){


        FB.api(
          '/xxx/events
access_token='xxxxxxx',
          'GET',
          {fields: "name,description"},
          function(response) {
              console.log('API response', response);
              $("#name").append(response.name);
              $("#description").append(response.description);
              }
        );
  });
});
</script>
```

I would appreciate if anyone could assist in just an example of code that loops thru all the events and displays the event name and description.

Thank you

Comment: just check out the response, the console.log for debugging is already there. you really need to learn how to handle json.

Comment: that being said, what access token are you using? you should not use any access token like that on the client.

Comment: whatever, i´ll just write it for you...but you REALLY need to think about security with your access tokens.

Comment: Thanks for the help Luschn...unlike those that down vote a question from someone that is learning... way to help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not tested, but it should work:

```
function(response) {
    if (response.data)
        var $name = $(document.getElementById('name')),
            $description = $(document.getElementById('description'));
        for (var i = 0, count = response.data.length; i < count; i++) {
            $name.append(response.data[i].name);
            $description.append(response.data[i].description);
        }
    }
}
```

Don´t use the slow jQuery selectors, cache selections and don´t do them in loops.